# C# & unity DI : interface property not being able to access inside class function which extend interface

Tags: c#, unity-container

my interface has one function and one property. the class which extend interface then we can access that property from a function declared with in same class. here i am using unity to dynamically call a function which return IDBConnection object.

when i am compiling code then getting error like

> The name 'ConType' does not exist in the current context

i am not being able to figure out where i made the mistake. so please some one see my full code and tell me where i am making the mistake and where and how to fix it.

### class code

```
public interface BBAConnections
{
    IDbConnection  CreateConnection();
    string ConType { get; set; }
}

public class BBAConnection : BBAConnections
{
    string ConType { get; set; } 

    public  IDbConnection CreateConnection()
    {
        string _connectionString = "";
        IDbConnection connection=null;

        if (ConType == "local")
        {
            _connectionString = "put here local db connection";
            connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(_connectionString);
        }
        else if (ConType == "remote")
        {
            _connectionString = "put here remote db connection";
            connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(_connectionString);
        }
        else if (ConType == "OrcsWeb")
        {
            _connectionString = "put here website db connection";
            connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(_connectionString);
        }
        else if (ConType == "Sage")
        {
            _connectionString = "put here sage connection";
            connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(_connectionString);
        }

        return connection;
    }
}

public static class Factory
{
    static IUnityContainer cont = null;

    public static BBAConnections initialize(string type)
    {
        BBAConnections oDbConnection = null;

        cont = new UnityContainer();
        cont.RegisterType<BBAConnections, BBAConnection>("local");
        cont.RegisterType<BBAConnections, BBAConnection>("remote");
        cont.RegisterType<BBAConnections, BBAConnection>("OrcsWeb");
        cont.RegisterType<BBAConnections, BBAConnection>("Sage");

        oDbConnection = cont.Resolve<BBAConnections>(type);
        oDbConnection.ConType = type;

        return oDbConnection;
    }
}
```

### calling **CreateConnection** function like this way

```
Factory.initialize("local").CreateConnection();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the declaration within your implementing class to

```
public string ConType { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, **C# is case sensitive**, so you should change all ID**b**Connection to **IDBConnection**.

Now, your interface says that anything inheriting from it must have a **CreateConnection method** and a **ConType property**.

In your BBAConnection class you should make a **public** string property named ConType.

That should fix your code, it should look like this :

```
public interface IDBConnection
{
    IDBConnection CreateConnection();
    string ConType { get; set; }
}

public class BBAConnection : IDBConnection
{
    public string ConType { get; set; }

    public IDBConnection CreateConnection()
    {
        string _connectionString = "";
        IDBConnection connection = null;

        if (ConType == "local")
        {
            _connectionString = "put here local db connection";
            connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(_connectionString);
        }
        else if (ConType == "remote")
        {
            _connectionString = "put here remote db connection";
            connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(_connectionString);
        }
        else if (ConType == "OrcsWeb")
        {
            _connectionString = "put here website db connection";
            connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(_connectionString);
        }
        else if (ConType == "Sage")
        {
            _connectionString = "put here sage connection";
            connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(_connectionString);
        }

        return connection;
    }
}

public static class Factory
{
    static IUnityContainer cont = null;

    public static IDBConnection initialize(string type)
    {
        IDBConnection oDbConnection = null;

        cont = new UnityContainer();
        cont.RegisterType<IDBConnection, BBAConnection>("local");
        cont.RegisterType<IDBConnection, BBAConnection>("remote");
        cont.RegisterType<IDBConnection, BBAConnection>("OrcsWeb");
        cont.RegisterType<IDBConnection, BBAConnection>("Sage");

        oDbConnection = cont.Resolve<IDBConnection>(type);
        oDbConnection.ConType = type;

        return oDbConnection;
    }
}
```